# Waiting until notifications have been added before continuing with the rest of my code?

Tags: swift

My app schedules 64 notifications at a time when the user hits the save button. If there was an error in adding a notification, I would like to display an error message. However, the adding of notifications is happening asynchronously, so I'm unable to catch an error in time. How can I make my thread wait until all notifications have been added before continuing? My variable errorSettingUpNotifications always equals false because of the async functions, so my error check at the bottom is currently not working.

```
    var errorSettingUpNotifications = false
    for i in 0...maxNumberOfReminders
    {
        let randomWordIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Int(words.count - 1))))
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        let identifier = "Word\(i)"
        content.title = "Word Of The Day"
        content.body = "\(Array(words)[randomWordIndex].key) - \(Array(words)[randomWordIndex].value)"
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: i, to: startDate)!), repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request){
            (error) in
            if error != nil
            {
                errorSettingUpNotifications = true
            }
        }
    }
    if (errorSettingUpNotifications == true)
    {
        SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: "There was an error setting up your notifications. Please check your internet connection and try again.")
    }
    else
    {
        SVProgressHUD.showSuccess(withStatus: "Settings saved successfully")
    }
```

Comment: Use a DispatchGroup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `DispatchGroup` to achieve that. From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup).

> DispatchGroup allows for aggregate synchronization of work. You can use them to submit multiple different work items and track when they all complete, even though they might run on different queues.

Here's how it works.

```
// Create a dispatch group
let group = DispatchGroup()

var errorSettingUpNotifications = false

for i in 0...maxNumberOfReminders {
    // New block started
    group.enter()

    // Setup notification

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            errorSettingUpNotifications = true
        }
        // Block completed
        group.leave()
    }
}

group.notify(queue: .main) {
    if errorSettingUpNotifications {
        // Show error message if failed
    }
}
```